# Why my .dll imported in python giving error response when this function is called?

Tags: c#, python-3.x, dll, import

Below is the C# code used to generate .dll file

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
//using RGiesecke.DllExport;
namespace ClassLibrary1
{
   public class Class1
   {
      //[DllExport("print", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
      public static void Main()
         {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
         }
   }
}
```

Below is the Python 3 code used to import .dll file and access function Main

```
import ctypes
from ctypes import *
obj = WinDLL("C:\\Users\\SL-SUM0- 
00179\\Desktop\\ClassLibrary1\\ClassLibrary1\\bin\\Debug\\ClassLibrary1.dll")
obj.Class1.Main()
```

I'm getting error as
[dll function Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/csdN9.jpg)

Comment: Is it a typo in your question or did you comment in your code the `DllExport` attribute?

Comment: Also, I have not used it, so I may be wrong, but... Aren't you trying to expose a custom function name for your exported function `print`? If you are, shouldn't it be something similar to `obj.print()`?

Comment: @Cleptus DllExport is in comment. I am trying to print in console Hello World in C#. I am calling Class1's function Main() to do the same in Python 3.

Comment: YOur code looks like a mix of [this two examples](https://gist.github.com/AlexArcPy/a9dd03519c0e7ec2f58f1ede89d60803)

Comment: You are somewhat right, I tried to run                  'import sys'
'import clr'
'sys.path.append(r"C:\Users\SL-SUM0-00179\Desktop\ClassLibrary1\ClassLibrary1\bin\Debug")'
'lb = clr.AddReference('ClassLibrary1')'
'from ClassLibrary1 import Class1'
'c = Class1()'
'c.Main()'     and it showed      AttributeError: module 'clr' has no attribute 'AddReference'

Comment: Also, I ran code 'using System;'
'using System.Collections.Generic;'
'using System.Linq;'
'using System.Runtime.InteropServices;'
'using System.Text;'
'using System.Threading.Tasks;'
'using RGiesecke.DllExport;'
'namespace ClassLibrary1'
'{'
'   public class Class1'
'    {'
'        [DllExport("Main", CallingConvention =' 'CallingConvention.Cdecl)]'
'        public static void Main()'
'        {'
'            Console.WriteLine("Hello World");'
'        }'
'    }'
'}'
 & then error came: The type or namespace name 'RGiesecke' could not be found (are ..... assembly reference?

Comment: If you are using the `RGiesecke.DllExport` the easiest way would be adding the Nuget package/reference. It is integrated in Visual Studio. BTW, you can edit your question and add whatever you want to it

Comment: Do I need to download it from here https://3f.github.io/DllExport/releases/latest/manager/       I got this link when I searched RGiesecke.DllExport in net